# Firebase in cloud messaging - default facebook/instagram browser won't open my reactjs PWA

Tags: reactjs, instagram, progressive-web-apps

Since i added Firebase in cloud messaging to my pwa built in reactjs, instagram and facebook default browser wont open my pwa from bio links.  I also added some code to check which type of browser i am using because without this code safari was just showing white screen.

```
if (
  navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1 &&
  navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") == -1
) {
  console.log("Using Safari");
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  facebook = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  google = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  const appCheck = firebase.appCheck();
  bd = app.firestore();
  archivos = app.storage();
} else {
  console.log("Not using Safari");
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  facebook = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  google = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  const appCheck = firebase.appCheck();
  bd = app.firestore();
  archivos = app.storage();
  messaging = firebase.messaging();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it adding

```js
if (
  navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1 &&
  navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") == -1
) {
  console.log("Using Safari");
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  facebook = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  google = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  const appCheck = firebase.appCheck();
  bd = app.firestore();
  archivos = app.storage();
} else if (
  navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Instagram") != -1 ||
  navigator.userAgent.indexOf("FBAN") != -1 ||
  navigator.userAgent.indexOf("FBAV") != -1
) {
  console.log("Using Instagram or Facebook browser");
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  facebook = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  google = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  const appCheck = firebase.appCheck();
  bd = app.firestore();
  archivos = app.storage();
} else {
  console.log("Not using Safari, Instagram or Facebook browser");
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  facebook = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  google = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  const appCheck = firebase.appCheck();
  bd = app.firestore();
  archivos = app.storage();
  messaging = firebase.messaging();
}
```